# Creating a textFile from multiple directories - PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to create a textfile in pyspark where logs are distributed in many different directories following the same logic. However I am scanning the doc for some time and besides specifying all directories seperated with commas, it doesn't see feasible.

logsample = sc.textFile("s3://[...]/2015/02/01/00/17/*transactions*")

Any idea how to specify the full range of seconds, minutes, jours, etc. ?

Comment: I saw some people recommending [ ] so I tried something like this : logsample = sc.textFile("s3://[...]/2015/02/01/00/[00-59]/transactions") but I get this error : py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the glob module

```
import glob
glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
```